# Use Secure String In Second Function

Tags: security, powershell

In function one, I read an object from a line and store it in a secure string.  The user should never be able to determine what's in the string and the actual value will be used in a second function.

```
$read_servername = ConvertTo-SecureString Read-File $file -AsPlainText -Force
```

This becomes the object `System.Security.SecureString`.  When I pass the secure string into the next function, it can't use the actual text of the secure string.  In searching, I haven't found a way to decrypt this secure string in the second function, but I need the second function to be able to use its value without the string ever being compromised.

Note that `ConvertFrom-SecureString` doesn't appear to decrypt it; for instance a value of "C:\Location\" won't be decrypted for use.

Thanks!

Comment: `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($read_servername))` should do it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You got it.  That's the answer, so I'll give you the green check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decrypting a SecureString isn't as easy as creating one. You can use the following to do it though:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.Inter‌​opServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($read_servername))
```

If the super long one-liner is intimidating you can make it two steps:

```
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.Inter‌​opServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($read_servername)
$PlainText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

Comment: Awesome; appreciate the assistance @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Too complicated. `(New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ('x', $read_servername)).GetNetworkCredential().Password`. Unfortunately secure strings aren't that secure in the first place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Wow, that's a heck of a shortcut for it. Never seen it done that way, but I'll have to remember it for the future.